# MSMQ not being emptied - removed the MSMQ limit chrashes server due to insuffient space

Tags: windows-server-2016, msmq

I currently having a issue with a message that keeps getting bigger and bigger.

[image]

and when I check each individual message

[image]

It is empty?..

Why are these not removed automatically?

These Messaes and the increasing MSMQ is causing our prod server to chrash, and restart with an empty queue.  btw. it is a private queue

Comment: How are you using the serverinternallog queue? It's not one MSMQ uses for itself so I assume one of your applications created it.

Comment: Yes, its ab private qurue, a log queue an application uses

Comment: Weirdly enoght is en recipient and destination the same ...

Comment: So your application should be processing the contents of the serverinternallog queue. MSMQ won't automatically do anything with the messages except store them for you.

Comment: The fact it's a private queue is unimportant. The messages will be Express (instead of Recoverable) which is why the queue is empty after the MSMQ service restarts. MSMQ does not persist Express messages.